# How to listen on all fetch API calls?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

We can modify the `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` to hijack all Ajax requests before. What's the equivalent if switching to the new browser's fetch API?

```
const originalRequestOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
  this.addEventListener('load', function() {
      // do something
  });
  originalRequestOpen.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: Patch `fetch` function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't recommend to modify native objects and functions (even the way you did with `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open`). But you can replace `fetch` function itselt. In the end it is just a function.

```js
(function(ns, fetch) {
  if (typeof fetch !== 'function') return;

  ns.fetch = function() {
    var out = fetch.apply(this, arguments);
    
    // side-effect
    out.then(({ ok }) => console.log('loaded', ok));

    return out;
  }

}(window, window.fetch))

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/userz')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works perfectly. However, it's strange on my project using webpack: I set `window.fetch` to my own function. In another file, the `window.fetch` is modified correctly but directly using `fetch` will use system's native function. Any suggestion on that? Currently, I create a new function `fetchModified` and change everywhere I use fetch.

Comment: @IvorZhou It's probably because it saves the native function within itself during construction... and your later changes don't affect that.